nested For Loops in Java
Currently struggling to get my head around nested Loops. Having some trouble completing this exercise and just wanted to know where I'm going wrong.
Exercise:
In Tad's postal service, each PO box is labelled with an integer followed by a letter. Given integers numRows and numColumns, output the label for each PO box, followed by a space. End each row with a newline.
Click here for example
Ex: If the input is 3 4, then the output is:
1A 1B 1C 1D
2A 2B 2C 2D
3A 3B 3C 3D
Note:
Rows are in ascending order. PO boxes in the first row all start with the integer 1.
Columns are in alphabetical order. PO boxes in the first column all end with the letter A.
Add an empty string at the beginning of the output to properly concatenate characters and integers.
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LoopPatterns {
   public static void main (String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      int numRows;
      int numColumns;
      int currentRow;
      int currentRowInteger;
      int currentColumn;
      char currentColumnLetter;
   
      numRows = scnr.nextInt();
      numColumns = scnr.nextInt();

      /* Your code goes here */
      for(currentRow = 0; currentRow < numRows; ++currentRow){
         currentColumnLetter = (char)('A' + currentRow);
         
         for(currentColumn = 1; currentColumn <= numColumns; ++currentColumn){
            System.out.print(currentColumn + "" + currentColumnLetter + " ");
         }
         System.out.println();     
      }

   }
}


You're setting currentColumnLetter using currentRow instead of currentColumn, and then using currentColumn for the digit instead currentRow.

Your logic is slightly off. I have made some amendments and tested the below which should get your desired outcome:
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numRows;
    int numColumns;
    int currentRow;
    int currentRowInteger;
    int currentColumn;
    char currentColumnLetter;

    numRows = scnr.nextInt();
    numColumns = scnr.nextInt();

    /* Your code goes here */
    for(currentRow = 1; currentRow <= numRows; ++currentRow){
        for(currentColumn = 0; currentColumn < numColumns; ++currentColumn){
            currentColumnLetter = (char)('A' + currentColumn);
            System.out.print(currentRow + "" + currentColumnLetter + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}

Notice how I define the currentColumnLetter within the 2nd for loop, rather than outside of it. I have also replaced the currentColumn referenced in the print statement with currentRow instead
